# How to enable polygon (geofence) editing enable,on clicking polygon itself, without clicking on Edit button

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

I an using react-leaflet and 'react-leaflet-draw', for creating fences on map.

I want to edit fence on clicking of fence itself only, not by clicking on edit button.I am using geoJson for creating fences,

So anybody can tell me about the property which allow fences in edit mode?

```
render() {
 return (
  <FeatureGroup>
    <EditControl
      position="bottomright"

      edit={{ remove: false }}
      draw={{
        marker: false,
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        polygon: false,
        polyline: false,
        circlemarker: false,
      }}
    />

{Object.values(this.props.geoFenceIdDataMapWithFlipCoordinates).
 map(geoFence => (
      <Polygon
        key={geoFence.id}
        color={`${geoFence.colorCode}`}
        positions={geoFence.geoData.geoJSON.geometry.coordinates[0]}
      />
    ))}

  </FeatureGroup>
   );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.icampanile.com/reactjs/react-leaflet-and-google-map-layer-with-controls-draw/ this url will have an example update `_onFeatureGroupReady` method with

```
leafletGeoJSON.eachLayer((layer) => { leafletFG.addLayer(layer) layer?.editing?.enable()})
```

Comment: Suggestion: Maybe place the solution first, then link to the source. In this way your answer gets more readable.